# PHP preg_replace_callback ignore id

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following code to match all letters except **i** and **d**.

```
/{([abcefghj-z]+)}/
```

How can I change it so that *i* and *d* can exist but not in that order (id).

Example strings:

```
/admin/users/{type}/{id}/edit
```

Only {type} would get replaced in the above example.

Example 2:

```
/admin/users/{type}/{id}/{supplied}/edit
```

In the above example both {type} and {supplied} would get matched.

Is this possible using regex?

**UPDATE**

The code I am using as per below post is:

```
$current = 'admin/users/{type}/{id}/changePassword';
$parameters = array('type' => 'administrators', 'id' => '1');

$path = preg_replace_callback('~\{(?!id\})[a-z]+\}~', function ($m) use ($parameters) {
        return $parameters[$m[1]]; 
}, $current);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for you: you need to use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (thus I added round brackets in `([a-z]+)`) to be able to get the value you need and I see you need to perform the search in a case-insensitive way (thus, I added `~i`):

```
$current = 'admin/users/{type}/{id}/changePassword';
$parameters = array('type' => 'administrators', 'id' => '1');

$path = preg_replace_callback('~\{(?!id\})([a-z]+)\}~i', function ($m) use ($parameters) {
//                                        ^      ^   ^
        return $parameters[$m[1]]; 
}, $current);

echo $path;
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/hW7DqQ)

With capturing group, `$m[1]` will hold "type", and thus you will get the value from the array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
\{(?!id\})[a-z]+\}
```

- `(?!id\})` asserts the previous token `{` would be followed by any but not of `id}`.
- If yes, then match one or more lower case letters and then `}`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4wM0/8)

**Example:**

This will replace all the matched substrings with `{foo}`.

```
preg_replace('~\{(?!id\})[a-z]+\}~', '{foo}', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4wM0/9)

Comment: When I use that regex on my function above I get: `preg_replace_callback(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: pls use `~` as regex delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get `Undefined offset: 1`

Comment: I've posted my full code at the bottom of my original post.