# PHP preg_replace multiple times

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to make a (template)system so I need to replace tags for a value. The template is stored in a file called 'template.tpl' and contains the following:

```
{title}
{description}

{userlist}
   {userid} is the id of {username}
{/userlist}
```

I have the following PHP script to rewrite the tags:

```
$template = file_get_contents('template.tpl');
$template = preg_replace('/{title}/', 'The big user list', $template);
$template = preg_replace('/{description}/', 'The big storage of all the users', $template);
```

Now I want to expand the script so I can rewrite the {userlist}. I have the following array with data:

```
$array = array(
    1    => "Hendriks",
    2    => "Peter"
);
```

How can I create a script that returns for example the following output?

```
The big user list
The big storage of all the users

1 is the id of Hendriks
2 is the id of Peter
```

I hope I have explained it as clearly as possible.

Comment: Can I suggest looking into Smarty or Twig?

Comment: I think you're going to need an array that represents array assignments, And can detect what type of content is assigned to each index so it can be smart and apply specific patterns matches if say the data is is an array vs string. eg how are you going to know that 
{userlist} requires iteration? assume a closing {/userlist} implies this?

Comment: @Scuzzy I only need those two functions so I think this is faster than using Smarty.

Comment: @Scuzzy Do you have example code?

Comment: Please check [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32608394/3832970),  is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start...

The idea behind this code is to find the content between each {tag}{/tag} and send it back through the function, this would permit nested foreach iteration as well, but there's not much checking eg case sensitivity will be an issue and it doesn't clean up unmatched tags. That's your job :)

```
$data = array();
$data['title'] = 'The Title';
$data['description'] = 'The Description';
$data['userlist'] = array(
  array('userid'=>1,'username'=>'Hendriks'),
  array('userid'=>2,'username'=>'Peter"')
);

$template = '{title}
{description}

{userlist}
   {userid} is the id of {username} {title}
{/userlist}';

echo parse_template($template,$data);

function parse_template($template,$data)
{
  // Foreach Tags (note back reference)
  if(preg_match_all('%\{([a-z0-9-_]*)\}(.*?)\{/\1\}%si',$template,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER))
  {
    foreach( $matches as $match )
    {
      if(isset($data[$match[1]]) and is_array($data[$match[1]]) === true)
      {
        $replacements = array();
        foreach( $data[$match[1]] as $iteration )
        {
          $replacements[] = parse_template($match[2],$iteration);
        //$replacements[] = parse_template($match[2],array_merge($data,$iteration)); // You can choose this behavior
        }
        $template = str_replace($match[0],implode(PHP_EOL,$replacements),$template);
      }
    }
  }
  // Individual Tags
  if(preg_match_all('/\{([a-z0-9-_]*)\}/i',$template,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER))
  {
    foreach( $matches as $match )
    {
      if(isset($data[$match[1]]))
      {
        $template = str_replace($match[0],$data[$match[1]],$template);
      }
    }
  }
  return $template;
}
```

Comment: Hi Scuzzy! Sorry for my late response. This code works great! Thank you for the explanation and the code.

Comment: You'll probably have lots of superfluous white-space all over the place too, you could wrap some of the code with `trim()` to address it, or just ensure all your formatting with HTML tags does the trick.